# Can't login to Target.com with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm working on a online purchase bot for target.com and I've run into a blocker. Upon providing correct username and password combination on the login page and clicking "login", I get the following error message on the target login page: "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again.". This only occurs when running through browser automation. Just wondering if there's a workaround for this issue. Here is my code thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

btn_sign_in_nav = "//span[text()='Sign in']"
btn_sign_in_drop_down = "//div[@id='accountMenu']//div[text()='Sign in']"
input_username_login = "//input[@id='username']"
input_password_login = "//input[@id='password']"
btn_submit_login = "//button[@id='login']"


def xpath_explicit_wait(xpath_val, time_sec):
    if type(time_sec) != int or type(xpath_val) != str:
        print("NUMERICAL VALUES ONLY!")
        driver.quit()
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, time_sec).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_val))
        )
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.quit()


def login_user(url, username, password):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_sign_in_nav).click()
    xpath_explicit_wait(btn_sign_in_drop_down, 5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_sign_in_drop_down).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(input_username_login).send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(input_password_login).send_keys(password)
    xpath_explicit_wait(btn_submit_login, 5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_submit_login).click()
```

Comment: Probably you should try using a different set of User Agents, take a look at this: [Random User Agents](https://pypi.org/project/random-user-agent/)

Comment: Check if username or password as trailing spaces from left and right in the code while inputing.

Comment: After about 100 runs, Target blocked my IP. I can't go to the login page anymore. Based on the attempts, the problem is caused by entering the username on the login page. If you exit the program before it enters any text into the username field, you can manually enter the user\pwd and login will succeed. I still don't know what's causing the error :(. I noticed the site is written in React so that may be contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Mike67 Yeah, I believe it's an authentication issue. Since logging in with Selenium doesn't seen to be working, we may need to use the "Requests" module to send requests and figure out how to pass information in a request body to their servers. I've tried copying and pasting the json payload received from the response of a successful sign-in attempt and sending a GET request with that payload, but says it's improperly formatted. Any way to reach out to you so we can continue discussing?

Comment: My account has a resume link with contact info.

Comment: @kobs24 Have you ever solved this problem? Having the same issue.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing as @ADJ lol

Answer (score 4):

There are detection mechanisms on sites like target that detect when you're using selenium and prevent the site from working.

More details can be found in the answer here: [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41220267#41220267)

PhoenixBot implements a mechanism that changes the contents of the driver so that it's undetectable. Use this same mechanism and your problems will vanish, as mine did!  :-D

https://github.com/Strip3s/PhoenixBot/blob/554441b3b6888a9be46b8aed6d364dc33da92e87/utils/selenium_utils.py#L150-L173

Answer (score 0):

There is a bot Phoenixbot, I can't speak for the functionality 100% but the auto login portion definitely works and is python. https://github.com/Strip3s/PhoenixBot/blob/master/sites/target.py

I've been attempting to figure out how exactly it's accomplishing that but no success replicating successfully in my own code. Maybe take a look.... If you figure it out I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have the ability to use Safari webdriver, then see the below code.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
driver.get('https://www.target.com/')
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="account"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="accountNav-signIn"]')))
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[@class="sc-hMqMXs sc-esjQYD eXTUDl"]')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys('foo')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('bar')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id=\'login\']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

As @Decian Shanaghy mentioned, Target seems to be bot protected, but Safari webdriver still works.

The time.waits are not needed, you can remove them if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeking a solution to this, see this answer at [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220267/3719114). I did a search through the `chromedriver` binary executable (MacOS in my case) and changed instances of `$cdc_` to `$abc_`.

I originally suspected Target employs a JavaScript solution to hunting selenium users. I confirmed this suspicion by using selenium to open a browser at `https://www.target.com` *without any automation*. I attempted to manually login and obtained a `401` response with the well known "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again." That didn't rule out a UI-based bot hunting solution but it pointed to a JavaScript hunter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating all occurrences of 'cdc_' with 'abcd'(any random string) in chromedriver.exe file  using hex editor neo and saved the file. This solution worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).